# jquery ie8 get text value = Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, html

I have two span tags inside two divs inside a master div

```
<div>
  <div>
    <span id="spanA">start text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span id="spanB">start text two</span>
 </div>
<div>
```

I use jquery 1.7.2 and am trying to get the default text value on the page load for span a & b, then onclick change the value of span a & b and then on toggle change them back.
On FF/chrome this works fine but ie8 is throwing an error

```
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

onload

```
spanAval = $('#spanA').text();
spanBval = $('#spanB').text();
```

onclick

```
$('#spanA').text("replace text");
$('#spanB').text("replace text two");
```

onToggle

```
$('#spanA').text(spanAval);
$('#spanB').text(spanBval);
```

in ie8 the text is replaced with "[object]"

I am sure I am missing something basic,
thanks
Art

Comment: Create reproducible example on jsfiddle please

Comment: Why do your divs have a letter in them `<div b> <div a>`?

Comment: you may have similar id's please show us full js fiddle to give you accurate answer !

Comment: Please make a JSfiddle with your code..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok it was something basic, I had the same name for the var as the id

```
spanA = $('#spanA').text();
```

and it failed in ie8 but worked in the other browsers FF/chrome etc , by changing the var name to a unique name it works in ie8

```
spanAval = $('#spanA').text();
```

thx for the quick replies

Comment: This makes so little sense, even for ie8, that I would have never figured it out without this question/answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

the last `div` is not closed. Jquery have several bugs as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use plain .innerText or .textContent (in Firefox) property i.e:

```
var text = $('selector')[0].innerText 
             ? $('selector')[0].innerText 
             : $('selector')[0].textContent // for Firefox
```

Comment: doesn't really explain why jQuery `text()` which has worked for many years cross browser is failing

Answer (score 1):

you can circumvent this error by declaring "var" before the variable in IE.

```
var spanA = $('#spanA').text();
```