# find() Function return null in IE8 and IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery

I work on XMLResponse and try to find count value from xmlresponse.For that i write this code

this is my response in alert box

[image: Response]

```
cnt = Math.ceil($(xmlResponse1).find("count").text()/250);
alert(cnt);
```

it works in IE9 but return null ni IE8 and IE7.

Please help me.
What Should have to do for solve this problem.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$()` function is not suited for parsing XML. Use [`$.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) before wrapping the elements inside a jQuery object.

```
var cnt = Math.ceil($($.parseXML(xmlResponse1)).find("count").text()/250);
alert(cnt);
```

You can see it working in IE8 in this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8erZG/)

Or in easier to read way, caching the parsed XML document:

```
var xmlDOM = $.parseXML(xmlResponse1);
var cnt = Math.ceil( $(xmlDOM).find("count").text()/250 );
```

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8erZG/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I think that text() does not work in ie7-8, try html():

```
cnt = Math.ceil($(xmlResponse1).find("count").html()/250);
```

Take a look at this question: [jquery ie8 get text value = Object doesn't support this property or method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167656/jquery-ie8-get-text-value-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method)